# CMake error could not find openmp_c unsuitable version Mac

Tags: c, macos, cmake

I ran the following command but an error was found. Any idea how to solve?
Running Mac OSX 10.12.6 (Sierra) with both integrated GPU (Intel Graphics HD 4000) and dedicated GPU (NVidia Geforce GT 650M). Intel CPU.

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ -DCMAKE_OBJCXX_FLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ -DOpenMP_C_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/local/include/libomp -DOpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/local/include/libomp -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib/libomp -DBINARY_PACKAGE_BUILD=ON -DRAWSPEED_ENABLE_LTO=ON -DBUILD_CURVE_TOOLS=ON -DBUILD_NOISE_TOOLS=ON -DDONT_USE_INTERNAL_LUA=OFF
```

output:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000039
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000039
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done

CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP_C: Found unsuitable version "3.1", but required is at
  least "4.5" (found -Xclang -fopenmp)


Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/local/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:592 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/local/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:542 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:89 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: `Found unsuitable version "3.1", but required is at least "4.5"` so by updating OpenMP_C your problem will solve it seems.

Comment: That is my understanding too, but how do I update openmp_c?

Comment: I never worked with that library, and I don't have a mac, but usually in linux(probably similar solution in mac) library names are like `libOpenMP_C` or `libOpenMP_C-devel`, you probably can update that library with your package manager, if you can't try to download, compile, and install it manually.

Comment: there are some links that maybe help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825416/missing-openmp-c-flags-openmp-c-lib-names and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414660/macos-cmake-and-openmp